# How do you bypass/disable VPN for a specific local adapter/address?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

I recently purchased a Loupedeck CT device for my mac and I absolutely love it!  However, I'm running into problems when connected to VPN since even though it appears to be USB, it looks like it's treating it as a networking device (I see it under Networking in System Preferences.)

I know the VPN Cisco AnyConnect is the culprit because as soon as I disconnect it again, the device suddenly starts working.

Not knowing much about networking, digging around I found the `route` command and tried this, but to no avail. (That is the IP and MAC addresses of the device.)

```
sudo route add -host 100.127.14.2 -link 04:22:c7:fe:00:8e
```

So... any thoughts on how to exclude a specific device/adapter from VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure [Split Tunneling](https://community.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/anyconnect-split-tunneling-local-lan-access-split-tunneling/ta-p/4050866) for AnyConnect (or ask your VPN administrator if you are not allowed to configure it)

EDIT: Info from the Cisco page above:

> AnyConnect settings to help alleviate that increased load
> Allow Local LAN Access
> Local LAN Access allows users to maintain access to their [RFC1918] home networks while connected to the secure VPN tunnel. The Administrator does not require knowledge of the actual addressing scheme when configuring Local LAN Access.  AnyConnect is capable of deterring the local network and adjusts the secure route list dynamically to exclude the home network from the tunnel.

Set up Split Tunneling in Cisco's Group Policy editor:

> Split Tunnel - ASDM Configuration – Access List - add you local network (e.g. 100.127.14.0/24)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Hi andaris, and welcome to SuperUser! :) This is exactly the information I was looking for!  That said, as @DavidPostill pointed out, it's a good idea to copy over the relevant information here in case the link ever goes dead.  If you can do that, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, I've added the most relevant parts. I've include the most important points, but I'm not sure whether the inclusion of copyrighted screenshots here would be appropriate.
Glad I could help, Mark Donohoe!